# Rails 4: Assign the records of one relation to another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have these models:

## ofert.rb

```
class Ofert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchasing_groups
end
```

## purchasing_group.rb

```
class PurchasingGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ofert
  has_many :group_goals
end
```

## group_goal.rb

```
class GroupGoal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchasing_group
end
```

In a controller action Im trying to do something like this:

```
copy_of_last_group_goals = @ofert.purchasing_groups.last.group_goals

@ofert.purchasing_groups.create
#@ofert.last_purchasing_group.save! adding this, did not work
#@ofert.save! This neither work.
@ofert.purchasing_groups.last.group_goals = copy_or_last_group_goals
@ofert.save
```

The above works great in local and I also try it from the console and it also work. I have my app deployed in heroku with postgresSQL, this is not working in production, it throws this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace group_goals because one or more of the new records could not be saved):
```

I tried saving the `purchasing_groups` and also saving the ofert as you could see in the commented lines, but that only worked in the console of my heroku app but not when I try it directly in the deployed app.

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you just not use ` a = @ofert.purchasing_groups.create`, then `a.group_goals = copy_or_last_group_goals`?

Comment: what is the difference? please help me understand what's going on =(

Comment: well, it is strangely even to copy `GroupGoal` instances also, for new `PurchasingGroup` you MUST create new list of group goals (according your schema) so you cant copy the array and that is because you have the only `belongs_to :purchasing_group` relation. on other case you mUST change your schema to many-to-many relation between  `PurchasingGroup`  and `GroupGoal`

Comment: Do you have a workaround for this? I just need to copy the last `GroupGoal` 's to the new `PurchasingGroup` that's it

Comment: what do you wish to get by copying the group goals?

Comment: Thanks I already solved this issue, take a look to my comments below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on me reading these lines of code

```
copy_of_last_group_goals = @ofert.purchasing_groups.last.group_goals
@ofert.purchasing_groups.create
@ofert.purchasing_groups.last.group_goals = copy_or_last_group_goals
@ofert.save
```

You want to create a new purchasing_group and fill it with the same group_goals that were the in purchasing_group that came before it? Is that right?

If so, then I would say **you can't** because you don't have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `GroupGoal` and `PurchasingGroup`.

Comment: Could you please provide a workaround? do you think `a=@ofert.purchasing_groups.create`, then `a.group_goals= copy_of_last_group_goals` would make the trick as the Russian guy suggested in the comments above?

Comment: Thanks for your tip, it was helpful, I finally found that the trick was use `dup` method instead of just assign them as a variable, here is a gist that explains very well about `dup` and `clone` ActiveRecord methods https://gist.github.com/liwh/1195027